Vagrant-libvirt: could not get preferred machine for /usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 type=kvm
I'm having issues with running an arm64 machine using vagrant with the vagrant-libvirt plugin.
Here's the Vagrantfile:
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  
  # Disable synced folders
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  
  # Machine setup
  config.vm.define "pi4b" do |app|
      
    app.vm.provider "libvirt" do |lv|
      lv.machine_arch = "aarch64"
    end

    app.vm.box = "generic/debian12"
    app.vm.box_architecture = "arm64"
    app.vm.hostname = "athena"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.58.2"
  end
end

When running vagrant up --provider libvirt, I get the following error:
Error while creating domain: Error saving the server: Call to virDomainDefineXML failed: invalid argument: could not get preferred machine for /usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 type=kvm

The latter part appears to be related to KVM (possibly a conflict with Virtualbox? No machine is running though), but I cannot find much of anything online.
Some stats on the machine in use:
OS: ArchLinux (x86_64)
Kernel: 6.9.1
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i7-12700H (20) @ 4.600GHz

How could I diagnose this issue? Is there another way to run an arm64 machine on Vagrant?

Did you try using the qemu driver for vagrant-libvirt instead of the default kvm one? Cf. the docs. To try it you would add lv.driver = "qemu" in your app.vm.provider block.

PS: I say this because I believe KVM doesn't work for cross-architecture emulation like you are doing (see this answer by the incomparable Gilles). Therefore you would have to resort to full emulation using QEMU, but that's just a supposition.
